# Jquery data table not working after update to new

Tags: jquery, datatables

I updated jquery datatable to newest version of jquery datatable. But after update it didn't get data from server.

```
var questionTable = $('#questionsTable').dataTable({

    "bServerSide": true,
    "bProcessing": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "sServerMethod": "POST",
    "sAjaxSource":app.baseUrl+ "/courses/question-api/get-question-list",
    "sAjaxDataProp":"aaData",
    "aoColumns":[
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        {

            "sName":"userName",
            "bSearchable":false,
            "bSortable":false,
            "mRender":function (oObj) {
                $markup = "<a id='view_link' class='adminlink' data-val='"+oObj.aData[4]+"' href='../courses/question/details?question_id=" + oObj.aData[4] + "' title='View'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open'></span></a><a class='adminlink'  title='Edit question' href='" + app.baseUrl + "/courses/question/edit?question_id=" + oObj.aData[4] +  "' ><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></a>"
                return $markup;
            }
        }
    ]

});
```

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: which version of datatable?

Comment: please check console...what error you are getting?

Comment: version 1.10.0
Console shows 
`Cannot read property '4' of undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First step, read this https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10-convert

A lot of your options are no longer valid in datatables 1.10. Try fix it, then ask your question again.

Comment: Thank, I already fixed my problem and thank you for your answer